# Windows 11: vertical scroll by mouse drag

Tags: windows, mouse, scrolling, delphi

Unlike other developer environments the latest **Delphi IDE** is still not able to properly handle touch gestures, thus taking the full advantage of a touchscreen laptop. (Again, we speak about IDE, NOT the applications built in Delphi.) That is, a touch gesture is treated as it would be a simple mouse click/movement.

This is mostly painful when the user wants to scroll, in this case rather a text block is selected, exacly like we would click and drag using a mouse.

So, is there any trick in Windows 11 to scroll a window by left clicking and dragging the mouse? Possibly when a modifier key (Shift, Ctrl, Alt, Win) is pressed. This would simulate the right touch gesture behavior of scrolling a window by touch-and-drag. Even a third-party (paid) app would be welcomed.
Or do you have any another idea for fixing the wrong delphi IDE behavior?

Comment: If your mouse has a scroll-wheel, it might already do what you ask.

Comment: And how to simulate scroll-wheel using the touch screen?

Comment: [Touch gestures for Windows](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/touch-gestures-for-windows-a9d28305-4818-a5df-4e2b-e5590f850741) says : "Scroll - 
Place two fingers on the screen and slide horizontally or vertically". Try it.

Comment: No, unfortunately this only works for apps which recognize touch gestures. Delphi is obviously mot one of them.